# What is best way to save password and id for offline use of the app xcode objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, offline

I am working with App that needs login same as Facebook. I want to use that password and id for the use even if they open the app offline.Even if app is removed from the background user can go in the other view controller that has been loaded previously .Right now I am getting login page every time in the offline which is my initial view controller.

Comment: k e y c h a I n

Comment: The [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) is the only right way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is saving the password in the keychain. [This tutorial is a very good start.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password) You can download the wrapper from the link in the tutorial.
Then you can save the password in the keychain as follow:

```
#import "KeychainWrapper.h"

// Save the password in the device keychain
KeychainWrapper *keychainWrapper = [[KeychainWrapper alloc] init];
[keychainWrapper mySetObject:encryptedpwd forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
[keychainWrapper writeToKeychain];
```

Later you can recover the password:

```
// Retrieve the pwd from the device keychain
KeychainWrapper *keychainWrapper = [[KeychainWrapper alloc] init];
NSString *pwd = [keychainWrapper myObjectForKey:@"v_Data"];
```

Comment: Answers that simply link to external sites are discouraged as the site might go offline. Instead you should copy the relevant parts of the linked site and add the link in case people want to read more about it.

Answer (score -3):

Store your id and Password in NSUserDefaults . And your login page has been set as initial ViewController , so it is loading every time after the app is killed.So for that you can take one NSUserDefaults and set YES to that value, as shown below

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:TRUE forKey:@"isLoggedIn"];
```

Write the above code , after successfull Login is done.

Now in AppDelegate's DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method Check the below condition.

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"isLoggedIn"] == true){
    // open your desired view controller
}
else{
   // open Login View Controller
}
```

Comment: This is a _really_ bad idea. Do **NOT** store the username and password in plain text in user defaults -- it's horribly insecure. This is exactly what the [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1) is for. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459879/how-to-store-a-string-in-keychain-ios, https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password

Comment: Then you can encode the username and password and then save it in documents directory.which will always safe

Comment: It's not the storage that is unsafe, it is the encryption portion of it -- in order to keep the username and password hidden, you need to correctly encrypt it, which is nontrivial. Instead of recreating the wheel (most likely doing it incorrectly, because encryption is _difficult_), it is a much better and much safer idea to use technology which exists specifically for this purpose: the keychain.

Comment: But if we want to save it for permanent then only one should use keychain.Or else no need to save in keychain

Comment: That's not true; any sensitive information that is stored for _any_ period of time should go through the keychain, not only permanent things. When storing user information, you have to think of possible attack vectors that someone could go through to, and consider that if someone wanted to get user data out of your app, they _can_. So, what's better -- putting in the effort to get encryption 100% correct (which is **hard**, and time-consuming) so you can write to disk, or use an already-existing implementation that's secure?

Comment: If you store sensitive user information on disk, no matter what you think, it can get accessed from the outside. (For instance, what if the user decided to jailbreak their phone, which is legal? All security considerations are out the window.) If you get the encryption even a little bit wrong, the data is compromised. If it's usernames and passwords, you've caused a _huge_ security hole for your users. The keychain, however, is secure always; it cannot be subverted in this way. Basically: there is simply no reason _not_ to use the keychain -- it's secure and does what you need!